# onmouseenter Event Listener not working on dynamically created html element

Tags: javascript, event-listener

The onmouseenter event on a dynamically created element is not working .It 
shows showOverlay() is not defined.
 index.html
 .
 .
 .

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navigation-control"><ul></ul></div>
  <div class="heading">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="filters d-flex justify-content-end"></div>
    <div class="container-wallpapers">
     <div class="col-wallpaper"></div>
     <div class="col-wallpaper"></div>
     <div class="col-wallpaper"></div>
     <div class="col-wallpaper"></div>
     <div class="loading-wallpapers">
       <h4>LOADING WALLPAPERS</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-toolbar" hidden>
      <div class="logo-toolbar">
        <h6><span>W</span>all<span>Truder</span></h6>
      </div>
        <ul>
          <li class="scroll-toolbar-gototop">
            <i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i>
            <h6>Top</h6>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
 <script src="assets/js/binder.js" type="module"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

binder.js

This is the function which creates an element when it's called.

```
       function createContainerWallpaper(src, username, usernameLink, 
           source, 
       sourceUrl){
        let containerWallpaper = document.createElement("div");
       containerWallpaper.setAttribute("class", "container-wallpaper");
       containerWallpaper.innerHTML = `<div class="main-wallpaper" 
       onmouseenter="showOverlay(event)">
           <img src="${src}"/>
           <div class="wallpaper-overlap">
             <div>
               <a href="${sourceUrl}" target="_blank">${source}</a>
               <a href="${usernameLink}" target="_blank">${username}</a>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>`;
       return containerWallpaper;
       }
```

The onmouseenter event listener

```
function showOverlay(event){
       console.log(event.target);
        }
```

I have also tried it by setting the event listener after the element is loaded using window.onload function but it didn't work. please help me out here

Comment: Is it in that binder file? why is it a module?

Comment: Where this `containerWallpaper` dom is getting appened

Comment: @epascarello yes, it is in the binder.js file. I made it a module because some of his function(which are not showed here) are being imported to another js file.

Comment: @brk It is being appended to div class = "col-wallpaper"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also create the `div` which will listen to the `mouseenter` event with `document.createElement` and assign the event listener to it and afterwards do the `innerHTML`.

Basic example:

```js
function showOverlay() {
  alert('Showing...');
}

const $demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
const $insertedDiv = document.createElement('div');

$insertedDiv.setAttribute('id', 'inserted');
$insertedDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', showOverlay);


$insertedDiv.innerHTML = '<span class="white">Appended with innerHTML</span>'

$demo.appendChild($insertedDiv);
```

```css
#demo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #CCC;
}

#inserted {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin: auto;
}

.white {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I made the div class="main-wallpaper" by using create element and assigned the event listener and it worked.